# Nested For Loops with SSH

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, nested, ip

I have setup nested loops - that reads a file for IP-Addresses and a file for commands (individually they work but as soon as i merged the two iterations SSH is not done on all the devices in the list. I did add some increments to see if code iterates properly..

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import paramiko
import sys
import time
import select
import re
import os

ip_add_file = open(r'ip-list','r')
cmd = open(r'cmd','r')
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
i=0
try:
   for host in ip_add_file:
          strip_host = host.strip()
          print strip_host + " START OF DEVICE"
          #i = i + 1
          #print i
              #ssh.connect(hostname=strip_host, username='test', password='test')
          #for cmds in cmd:
          ssh.connect(hostname=strip_host, username='test', password='test')
          i = i + 1
          print i

                 # strip_cmd=cmds.strip()
                 # print strip_cmd
          for cmds in cmd:
             strip_cmd=cmds.strip()
             print strip_cmd
             stdin,stdout,stderr = ssh.exec_command(strip_cmd)
             for line in stdout.readlines():
                 print strip_host + "~  " +  line.strip()
                 #ssh.close()
except paramiko.SSHException:
 print "Connection Failed"
 quit()
ssh.close()
```

File contents:

```
Running on machine itself:
cat ip-list
127.0.0.1
localhost
127.0.0.3

cat cmd
ls
```

Result:

```
ip route
ls
vm-linux:~/scripts$ ./t.py
127.0.0.1 START OF DEVICE
1
ls
127.0.0.1~  bin
127.0.0.1~  boot
127.0.0.1~  cdrom
127.0.0.1~  dev
127.0.0.1~  etc
127.0.0.1~  home
127.0.0.1~  initrd.img
127.0.0.1~  initrd.img.old
127.0.0.1~  lib
127.0.0.1~  lib64
127.0.0.1~  lost+found
127.0.0.1~  media
127.0.0.1~  mnt
127.0.0.1~  opt
127.0.0.1~  proc
127.0.0.1~  root
127.0.0.1~  run
127.0.0.1~  sbin
127.0.0.1~  snap
127.0.0.1~  srv
127.0.0.1~  sys
127.0.0.1~  tmp
127.0.0.1~  usr
127.0.0.1~  var
127.0.0.1~  vmlinuz
localhost START OF DEVICE
2
127.0.0.3 START OF DEVICE
3
```

Comment: Iterators can only be iterated over *once*. You need to reopen the command file inside the first loop, or otherwise reset the file pointer before trying to iterate over it a second time.

Comment: Put `cmd.seek(0)` before the `for cmds in cmd:` loop.

Comment: Thanks Barmar and chepner! it did the trick!! Thanks!